# How to make python pyinstaller executable sharable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have tried a lot but I cant wrap my head around it. I make a lot of tkinter GUIs that I would like to share with others, but I am not able to. I use pyinstaller to create an executable out of it and mailing the compressed folder. It still doesn't seem to work as warnings are raised.

Some of the warnings include things like 'this folder has an executable file that might not be safe.'

The executable GUI works completely fine on my computer.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -n GUI -i icon.ico -w main.py
```

How am I supposed to make an executable that is sharable?

Comment: You need to share more details. What warnings happen? Any screenshots or traceback?

Comment: Difference between OS? Are you trying to compile "tkinter" to Android?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very helpful section called *When things go wrong*. I suggest you work through it. Your question does not have nearly enough information for anyone to tell you what the problem is. For example, you do not provide your `.spec` file. And if you don't know what that is, and your application has a lot of dependencies, then that is the place to start looking for a solution. Also be aware that `pyinstaller` will not cross-compile. Using, say, a 64-bit Windows Python installation, that is the only platform you can target.

Comment: I am curious why this has 2 upvotes.

Comment: No. Actually it is tkinter for windows itself.

Comment: The "warning" sounds like an antivirus, or Windows's SmartScreen. You can usually bypass those warnings.